# Is it possible to "blackbox" or skip other extensions when debugging vscode extensions?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-extensions

I have an issue where my development environment has a few large extensions in it, and debugging my *own* extension using the "All exceptions" and/or "Promise rejects" breakpoints will hit on them quite frequently.

I am aware of the `skipFiles` option in the launch configuration, and that you can use a custom "Data" folder when launching `code` with the `--user-data-dir` option, but neither of these solutions seem to work for me. I can't figure out how to find generically define the extensions folder with `skipFiles`, and `--user-data-dir` doesn't seem to work as I'd expected and doesn't seem to be for my purpose.

To put it plainly, my ideal situation would be to use the debug shortcut `F5` and for a completely sterile version of vscode to launch with only my extension loaded and settings which aren't inherited from my development environment.

In the [following image of a breakpoint being hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rdOn.png), you can see that the first party extension "git" in the path "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/src/git.ts" is still being tracked. The command line switch `--disable-extensions` does not exclude this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable all other extensions when debugging your own extension via the [`--disable-extensions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions) flag. Just pass it via the `args` attribute in your `launch.json`:

```json
"args": [
    "--disable-extensions"
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works as expected, as there are still breakpoints being hit in an extension with all three automated breakpoints selected.

Comment: but after I add this arg, the launched vscode opens a new file named '--disable-extensions' -_-!

Comment: I have found the problem: you need append the option value `--disable-extensions=1`, otherwise it will be explained as input argument instead of option.